# Why does this odd symbol keep showing up when i write to text files?

Tags: c#, ssis

I can't copy the symbol into this text are, but it just looks like a small little box.

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("\\\\WEBSQL4\\ssis\status.txt");
//To Do: Write loop and Add environment to file
tw.WriteLine(string.Concat(Dts.Variables[0].Value.ToString(), "|PROCESSING|MAIN|", DateTime.Today.ToString()));
tw.Close();
```

When I go to inspect the file in NotePad, there are these little boxes.  What could possibly be causing this?

Comment: Open that file in other editor - wordpad or notepad++ and see what happen?

Comment: "Odd" characters should usually set alarm bells ringing in your head regarding encoding. :)

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#:". That makes it harder to see the actual title, and we have tags for this purpose on [so].

Comment: Are the boxes at the end of the lines, or distributed through the file? Sounds like an encoding issue. Try specifying the encoding: TextWriter output = new StreamWriter 
                   (new FileStream (args[1], FileMode.Create),
                    Encoding.Unicode)

Comment: notepad ++ will also give me this issue

Comment: can you post where do you see the odd chars?? also what do you see if you open the file in hex???

Comment: What is the data type of variable at ordinal position 0?

Comment: the character is always the first character in the text file

Comment: @Gbnocchi : i am not sure what you mean can i attach a file? sry noob here

Comment: @iwant_B_smrtr Could you post not the string content but the byte values of the file content. Not "ABC" but 65 66 67.

Answer (score 0):

The small boxes are carriage returns - or line feeds